# Customizing checkout form-login.php template does not display button text

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, checkout

I want to display a link in php via echo but the problem is that only the **`class`** and the **`id`** from my **`<a>`** tag is shown but the **`data-toggle`** is not displayed on the website and the link doesn't work without this attribute.

This is how it looks like in this extract of template file:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() || 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_checkout_login_reminder' ) ) {
    return;
}

$info_message  = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_login_message', __( 'Returning customer?', 'woocommerce' ) );
$info_message .= " <a href=\"#modal-login\" class=\"login\" data-toggle=\"ml-modal\">" . __( 'Click here to login', 'woocommerce' ) . "</a>";
wc_print_notice( $info_message, 'notice' );
```

And this is the outputted source code in my browser:

```html
<a href="#modal-login" class="login">Klicke hier, um dich anzumelden.</a>
```

Does anybody know the reason?

I've search in the Internet for a solution, but it looks like that I'm the only person who has this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: What browser are you using? Have you tried it in different ones?

Comment: You need to show more code. What you've written should work by itself, so something else must be going on.

Comment: @Barmar I've added more code for you. I've tried it in Opera, Firefox, IE 8+ but everywhere the same problem

Comment: Maybe it's something related to `wc_print_notice()`? I don't know WooCommerce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems that you are trying to customize the code of **`checkout/form-login.php`** WooCommerce template via your active theme (*This are the official related docs: [**Template Structure + Overriding Templates via a Theme**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)*).

*Briefly (if not done yet), you will need to copy from woocommerce plugin folder, a subfolder named **`templates`** to your active child theme (or theme) and to rename it **`woocommerce`**. After that you find inside that new **`woocommerce`** folder in **`checkout`** subfolder a template named **`form-login.php`**.*

Here is complete code of the template, with a revisited functional customization as you are trying to do it. Open/edit **`form-login.php`** template and replace the code by this:

```html
<?php
/**
 * Checkout login form
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/form-login.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

if ( is_user_logged_in() || 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_checkout_login_reminder' ) ) {
    return;
}

$info_message  = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_login_message', __( 'Returning customer?', 'woocommerce' ) );

//////////////// HERE IS YOUR CUSTOMIZATION ///////////////
$info_message .= ' <a href="#modal-login" class="login" data-toggle="ml-modal">' . __( 'Click here to login', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';
wc_print_notice( $info_message, 'notice' );
?>

<?php
    woocommerce_login_form(
        array(
            'message'  => __( 'If you have shopped with us before, please enter your details in the boxes below. If you are a new customer, please proceed to the Billing &amp; Shipping section.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'redirect' => wc_get_page_permalink( 'checkout' ),
            'hidden'   => true
        )
    );
?>
```

Then save. This time the output should work as expected.

Comment: @LoiceTheAztec I've made the customization you said, but I still get my code without data-toggle="ml-modal" :/

Comment: Oh okay, who and how did you see this? :o You help me so much, don't know how to thank you this... :/

Comment: @Johnny97 Sorry I have tried even with a custom javascript to add this, but is not possible… There is an other script that removes it, even with a delay… I am able to add any attribute in the `<a>` tag but it doesn't accept `data-toggle` one. You can un-accept my answer as it's not good.

Comment: I have an Idea how it could work if this is possible. Do you know a way to say: This String in php should not have any affect from a script?

Comment: This doesn't work as this, because I think is some ajax script that is responsible, and I don't know the way to prevent this without breaking the other javascript functionalities on the checkout process... May be try to ask a new question based on this. I don't know what to say more. I  am stuccoed as you are.